# Changing theme colors in Materialize with Sass (React)

Tags: reactjs, sass, materialize, theming

I can't seem to find many tutorials about over-riding colors in Materialize in Sass. The only tutorial I can find is on downloading the Sass files and then integrating this in the project directly by editing the _variables.scss and re-compiling to get the new CSS file.

Ideally I would like to use the NPM package so I don't have to manually keep updating the Sass folder. So, my aim is to use the NPM package "materialize-css" and over-ride the colors in Sass somehow.

I have setup a React test project. The code I have is as follows:

INDEX.JS

```
 import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.scss';
    import App from './App';
    import "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"; //This is for JS functionality

    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

index.scss

```
@import "materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss";

// $primary-color: #346BA7 !default;
// @import "materialize-css/sass/components/_variables.scss"; 
// **The commented lines above do not work**.

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
}

...
```

In the index.scss, this is where I would like to do the theming. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you watch this tutorial? https://medium.com/@mattdlockyer/youre-using-materialize-css-wrong-470b593e78e9

Answer (score 1):

The color variables are defined in the SASS source using `!default`, so all you need to do is define the same variables *before* importing the main materialize.scss, i.e:

```
$primary-color: color("blue-grey", "lighten-2");
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%);
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%);
$secondary-color: color("amber", "lighten-1");

@import '../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
```

N.B. the use of `!default` in the SASS source means that they are only defining the variable *if it is not already defined*.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out but not sure if it is the best method so if anyone knows anything better, please let me know.

```
@import "../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/_color-variables.scss";

$primary-color: color("blue-grey", "lighten-2") !default;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$secondary-color: color("amber", "lighten-1") !default;

@import '../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
```